# How to receive H264 stream via RTP and store to file?

Tags: file, stream, store, h.264, rtp

I'm trying to make a server that receives RTP/H264 video streams from android clients and stores these to file.

Currently I'm using VLC in the server, which works well.  However, I am worried that VLC is a heavyweight solution that may not scale well.  As I'm not actually playing the video, only saving it to file, I thought there must a be a more efficient solution.

Currently I'm planning on using an Amazon ec2 instances, so the goal is to serve as many clients as possible per instance.

I'm flexible (willing to learn) on the language side, I'd like to choose the right language for the job.

So, does anyone know of a good, scalable way to store these streams to files?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

FFmpeg or libav look promising.  Looking into them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need an library that supports rtp stack server side, so you can extract the payload and just append to a file as it comes. ffmpeg is a great choice, and it does have rtp stack and it also it can generate containers(MP4,...) for you as well; if needed. Actually VLC uses ffmpeg's libav library under the hood.